# How to use the ls command to show all files except those ending in a specific string

Tags: bash, command-line, ls, filenames

I have a directory with files of all kinds and I wanted to use the `ls` command to list all of them, except those with a name that ends in `.config`, but I do not get how to do it.

Comment: Which shell do you use?

Comment: I use the bash shell

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/216995/10622916

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/471581/117549

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As in the related post, in bash set extended globbing then ask `ls` for those files that don't end in `.config`:

```
shopt -s extglob
ls -d -- !(*.config)
```

By default, files that start with a period (dot, `.`) are not shown; you can see them by enabling another shell option:

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

Comment: Nitpicking: This is not using `ls` to do anything special, but it's using the shell's file name expansion to give the correct list to `ls`. The `ls` utility is still used as it's always been used.  This does not matter much unless one cares about how things actually happen (`ls` does not expand globs).

Comment: You have to squint to read it with my interpretation : that I'm asking `ls` to list *these* files; you're correct that ls is not expanding anything.

Comment: "My eyes are old and bent."

Comment: what @Kusalananda is saying is very important. It will save you life some day. Well may be save your life, but it will definitely save you from a lot of problems.